# Trying to change the Alignment of setText() method?

Tags: java, android, css

I am trying to change the Alignment of "setText" method of "Textview".To be clear,On my emulator I'm trying to align set the Text of "setText".However I am unsuccessful in doing that.Below posted is my code.

```
       <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="#ff00ff"
        android:text="@string/username"
        android:background="#00ff00"
        android:id = "@+id/text1"
        android:textColorHighlight="#000000"
        android:textIsSelectable="true"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>
```

Attached is the java code

```
       TextView t1,t2;
       t1 = (TextView)(findViewById(R.id.text1));
       System.out.println(t1.toString());
       tableRow = new TableRow(getApplicationContext());
       t1 =new TextView(getApplicationContext());
       t1.setText("Username");
       t1.setTextSize(20);
       t1.setTextAlignment(Gravity.BOTTOM); //This is what I'm trying!!
       t1.setTextColor(Color.RED);
       t1.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
       t1.setPadding(15, 35, 15, 15);
       t1.setAllCaps(true);
       t1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.cellgrey);
       tableRow.addView(t1);
```

Any Suggestions would be helpful

Answer (score 0):

Text alginment doesn't take a gravity constant.  It has its own set.  See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setTextAlignment%28int%29 So what you're doing is really off.

Generally the right way to do it is to either set the layout_gravity of the textview, or to align the textview itself the way you want, depending on the size of the string and effect you're trying to get.